# Conditional <remap>

Tags: ros, roslaunch, xml, topics, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to control topic remaps using `roslaunch` command-line arguments (i.e. by setting ROS parameters).

Is there a way to cause a `roslaunch` XML topic remap to be conditional? I'm looking for behavior like the `<group if="$(arg remap)">` tag.

I tried putting a `<remap>` into a `<group>`, but this only seems to remap topics for the nodes in that group.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208696/conditional-%3Cremap%3E/) by [Adam Allevato](https://answers.ros.org/users/21561/adam-allevato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 194 on 2015-05-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`if` and `unless` can be used on any tag, not just `group`, so you should be able to achieve what you want with something like:

```
<remap if="$(your_condition)" .. />
```

See also [wiki/roslaunch/XML - If and unless attributes](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#if_and_unless_attributes):

> **All tags** support if and unless attributes, which include or exclude a tag based on the evaluation of a value [..]

(emphasis mine).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4